# Filtering word data nouns by subfield?

Tags: curated-data, filtering, linguistics

I am making string combinations using `WordData` and would like to filter all nouns that come from a specific professional specialization.  For example, the nouns in the English dictionary are dominated by biology and medical terms that are not useful to me.  There is a `UsageField` and `UsageType` property tag that can be used, which shows promise, but these are mostly blank, even when the usage seems self evident (?).

For example:

```
nouns = WordData[All, "Noun"];
WordData[#, "UsageField"] & /@ nouns[[3000 ;; 3010]] // TableForm
```

Returns a set of things I'd like to get rid of but have no filter for without knowing in advance what the term is:

```
{
 {{"Alnico", "Noun"} -> {}},
 {{"Alnus", "Noun"} -> {}},
 {{"Alnus crispa", "Noun"} -> {}},
 {{"Alnus glutinosa", "Noun"} -> {}},
 {{"Alnus incana", "Noun"} -> {}},
 {{"Alnus maritima", "Noun"} -> {}},
 {{"Alnus rhombifolia", "Noun"} -> {}},
 {{"Alnus rubra", "Noun"} -> {}},
 {{"Alnus rugosa", "Noun"} -> {}},
 {{"Alnus serrulata", "Noun"} -> {}},
 {{"Alnus veridis", "Noun"} -> {}}
}
```

Any thoughts on how to remove such terms?  Perhaps interfacing more directly with the richer computational knowledge in WolframAlpha?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `WordList` with the `CommonWords` type?

Comment: That seems to do the job.  I'm sort of embarrassed I didn't think if it myself; thanks very much for the quick response and easy solution.